# How do I distribute/share a project/product?

Tags: 8

I have a site that I've built with Drupal 8, using composer and git to manage the code base. It's a fairly simple site that includes a handful of third-party modules, a few custom views, and a custom theme.

I am thinking about the best way to share this site as an open solution for others that may want to use it for themselves.

Should I consider an installation profile, a distribution, or just a git repository?

Is there any reason I couldn't share my Drupal 8 project simply by sharing the composer.json file and configuration exported data?

Comment: `Is there any reason I couldn't share my drupal 8 project simply by sharing my composer.json and config export?` People like and probably expect 1 click installs in this day in age. Plus, this is not newbie or dummy proof.

Comment: @NoSssweat true, ease of install is probably a big enough reason to build an install profile/distro. Even though installing drupal these days is fairly tricky and involves composer, the actually install wizard prevents the user from doing a manual configuration import.